# Cron job failed to run just on every LAST Friday of every month

Tags: unix, cron

I asked this question here before and I went using this code for the job. The issue is that the cron job ran, but it should only run on Fridays, instead it ignored the "5" for Friday and ran on 06/26 (correct), 06/27-06/28-06/29 and 06/30. Can anyone suggest the reason why it ignored the "5" for Friday and still ran for all the dates in the range and how it can be fixed?

```
0 1 25-31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 5 code.pl
0 1 24-30 4,6,9,11        5 code.pl
0 1 22-28 2               5 code.pl
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

See this answer for something very similar

https://superuser.com/questions/348348/crontab-day-of-week-vs-day-of-month

When you specify both day-of-the-week and day-of-the-month is will run when either are true.

You would need to use the cron time/date settings, and add a condition to the command, such as:

`0 1 22-28 2 *               test $(date +%a) = "Fri" && code.pl`

Comment: Admin type people, feel free to delete as a dupe

Comment: I like that, but I am getting a "bad username", setting this up as a test: 
35 9 24-30 4,6,9 * test $(date +%a) = "Mon" && user cd /var/www/code; perl perl.pl 2>&1 | tee -a error.log

Comment: I fixed the issue I was having above, the username "user" needs to be before the "&&".